# React Idle Timer with BrowserRouter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron

I'm attempting to use the React Idle Timer to go to a lock screen after 15 minutes.

The problem I am having is redirecting the page. I am using electron with react and the react BrowserRouter. Because of this I can't use window.location.assign('/clock'); (or similar window.location) method to redirect the page. Typically in my components I use:

```
this.props.history.push("/clock");
```

This works within the components that are within the Switch of the BrowserRouter. However, I need the React Idle Timer to be at the top level and when I use props.history.push inside the ***onIdle*** function I get the message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
```

```html
class AppRouter extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.idleTimer = null;
    this.onAction = this._onAction.bind(this);
    this.onActive = this._onActive.bind(this);
    this.onIdle = this._onIdle.bind(this);
  }

  _onAction(e) {
    console.log("user did something", e);
  }

  _onActive(e) {
    console.log("user is active", e);
    console.log("time remaining", this.idleTimer.getRemainingTime());
  }

  _onIdle(e) {
    console.log("user is idle", e);
    console.log("last active", this.idleTimer.getLastActiveTime());

//need to push to  /clock after 15 minutes
//window.location.assign('/clock');  -- WORKS in browser, but not with Electron

// this.props.history.push("/clock"); -- gives Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

//can't place <IdleTimer inside BrowserRouter because it only allows 1 thing within.

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <IdleTimer
          ref={ref => {
            this.idleTimer = ref;
          }}
          element={document}
          onActive={this.onActive}
          onIdle={this.onIdle}
          onAction={this.onAction}
          debounce={250}
          timeout={1000 * 60 * 0.1}
        />

        <BrowserRouter>
          <div>
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/institution" component={Institution} />
              <Route path="/location" component={Location} />
              <Route path="/timezone" component={TimeZone} />
              <Route path="/clock" component={Clock} />
              <Route path="/" component={PreflightCheck} />
            </Switch>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<AppRouter />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

What is the correct way to redirect to a component at the top level outside of the BrowserRouter tags?

I have also tried this:

```
import { createHashHistory } from 'history'
export const history = createHashHistory()
```

and then calling history.push('/clock');

That only seems to append /clock to the current page that I am on and I get this message:

```
Hash history cannot PUSH the same path; a new entry will not be added to the history stack
```

Comment: Since routes are just components now, maybe it makes sense to move the idle-timeout behavior into a new component that wraps the routes? Then you could use history.push as you usually do.

Comment: You can use withRouter: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter

Comment: Does IdleTimer not allow you to pass children? You could replace the div inside the BrowserRouter with the IdleTimer then have the switch sit inside that if so.

Comment: The history.push continues to work fine in the other components. I need it to work inside the onIdle action method that is above the render area.

Answer (score 2):

Create history (you can use npm install history):

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
const history = createBrowserHistory();
```

Then place the idle timer within Router. BrowserRouter does not seem to work with history like Router does in this situation.

```
<Router history={history}>
      <div>

  <IdleTimer
          ref={ref => {
            this.idleTimer = ref;
          }}
          element={document}
          onActive={this.onActive}
          onIdle={() =>  this.checkplayerstatus(history)}
          onAction={this.onAction}
          debounce={250}
          timeout={1000 * 60 * 15}
        />
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/institution" component={Institution} />
          <Route path="/location" component={Location} />
          <Route path="/timezone" component={TimeZone} />
          <Route path="/clock" component={Clock} />
          <Route path="/" component={PreflightCheck} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </>
```

And then in the onIdle function you can do this: "whatevervariableyoupassashistoryfromonidle".push("/clock").

Answer (score 0):

```
   If you are using tsx means ,
      _onIdle=(e)=> {
          window.location.href = "/your_location";
       }
    or if you are using js means,
      _onIdle=(e)=> {
          window.location = "/your_location";
       }

<IdleTimer
          ref={ref => {
            this.idleTimer = ref;
          }}
           element={document}
      onActive={this.onActive}
      onIdle={this.onIdle}
      onAction={this.onAction}
          debounce={250}
          timeout={1000 * 60 * 15}  // 15 minutes
        />
```